# What's the meaning of the angle brackets on LINQ methods in Intellisense? (Contains<>, Count<>, Distinct<>, etc.)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, linq, extension-methods, intellisense

They usually involve generics.  But some methods with generics don't have them, and not all extension methods have them.

They've just "been there" since day one, we've all seen them; but I realized I still don't know what they mean, and I can't find the answer anywhere.  Now it's really bugging me.  Google just turns up results that are about XML, etc.

Is this officially documented anywhere?  Thanks.

EDIT: Well that's just great.  Since I just created an account to make my first Stack Overflow post, to get an answer for this burning question; I'm not allowed to post my pretty Intellisense picture, or create a new tag "angle-brackets".  I love Stack Overflow, but... what a welcome!

Maybe my problem is that they aren't actually called "angle brackets"... ??

Anyway, I guess if you really want to see my beautiful screenshot you could manually go to:

[Distinct>< http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/6a6c2f3268.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/6a6c2f3268.png)

Bump me up please so I can include it in the post, thanks.  ;)

Comment: ReSharper hides them ... when you installed it, you can goto `Options -> IntelliSense -> General` and choose ReSharper's own intellisense or the one of VS

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers and votes.  I know generics, but wasn't sure of the specific designation of the angle brackets (in Intellisense).

I guess my confusion was seeing two versions for something like: new int[] { 1, 2 }.Sum

...one (without angle brackets) for an extension method on a generic class, and one (with angle brackets) for a *generic* extension method on a generic class!

I appreciate the explanations and confirmation.

Comment: By the way, does anyone have an MSDN or other link tying generic methods specifically to that mark in Intellisense?  Not that I don't believe you... it's just strange that I can't find *anything*.

Comment: Thank you James Westgate and SLaks for fixing the tag and adding the image!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These methods are generic.

However, the compiler automatically infers the generic type parameter from the method call, so you don't need to use the brackets when calling the method.

For example, if you have an `IEnumerable<int> myNumbers`, the following four statements are equivalent:

```
myNumbers.Count();
myNumbers.Count<int>();
Enumerable.Count(myNumbers);
Enumerable.Count<int>(myNumbers);
```

In the first and third calls, the compiler infers the `int` parameter because `myNumbers` is an `IEnumerable<int>`.

The `Count` extension method is declared (in System.Core.Dll) like this:

```
public static int Count<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source);
```

Answer (score 2):

they are for generics.  When you use the functions you don't always have to put in the  because in many cases the compiler can figure it out by context.

Answer (score 1):

They are [generic method signatures.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb(VS.80).aspx)  I would suggest you learn up on them.

A couple interesting things to note about generics:  First, they are not generic after compilation.  All types are resolved and set in stone before you run your app.  Second, the compiler can often figure out what you mean, so you don't have to be explicit about it.  For instance, if a method signature is `DoSomething<T>(t withThis)`, you could invoke this method like `DoSomething<string>("with me")` *or* you could omit the generic type: `DoSomething("with me")`.  This is because the compiler looks at the types passed into the method as arguments and figures out the type parameter for the method.  Awesome.

Comment: Good link.  That's the sort of thing I was looking for, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It means the method are generic, ie they are not type specific.

Good infomation on Generics:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Jon Skeet's book [C# in Depth](http://csharpindepth.com/) goes into generics and linq in detail and cleared a lot of this up for me - I can highly recommend it.